# Name spaces in php

Tags: php, namespaces, static-members

I am kind of confused about using name spaces in php,would try to explain using the problem I have with one of my project

I have a class under a namespace as

```
namespace BigBlueButton;
class BigBlueButton
{
   public function createMeeting($createMeetingParams, $xml = '')
    {
       //some code

        return new CreateMeetingResponse($xml);
    }
}
```

I use it as

```
use \BigBlueButton;
    $bbb = new BigBlueButton\BigBlueButton();

//then I try to reference the variable $bbb in a function but I can't 

    function easymeet_create_meeting($id) {


 // $bbb = new BigBlueButton\BigBlueButton(); I don't want to create a new object here but reference the object I created above,something like this
      $bbb=BigBlueButton\bbb;
}
```

But I can't seem to access the above variable i.e. $bbb , I tried `global $bbb` ,but `$bbb` doesn't seem to be in the global namespace, I understand I am trying to access a constant $bbb in the above code, but I showed it anyway to tell what I am trying to do

Comment: BigBlueButton\bbb is not a variable. it's a namespace reference...

Answer (score 2):

Namespacing does not extend to variables like that:

> In the PHP world, namespaces are designed to solve two problems that
>   authors of libraries and applications encounter when creating
>   re-usable code elements such as classes or functions:
>
> 1. Name collisions between code you create, and internal PHP classes/functions/constants or third-party
>      classes/functions/constants.
> 2. Ability to alias (or shorten) Extra_Long_Names designed to alleviate the first problem, improving readability of source code.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Your class declaration is fine, but you've mis-used the `use` keyword as it should refer to specific classes, not a namespace.

```
use \BigBlueButton\BigBlueButton;

function easymeet_create_meeting($id, BigBlueButton $bbb) {
    /* ... */
}

$bbb = new BigBlueButton();
$result = easymeet_create_meeting(1234, $bbb);
```

You'll notice that I've also moved `$bbb` into the function parameters because [global state is the devil](https://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it). It's also [type-hinted](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) because why not?

Better yet:

```
class BigBlueButton implements ButtonInterface {}
class BigRedButton implements ButtonInterface {}
```

And:

```
function easymeet_create_meeting($id, ButtonInterface $bbb) {}
$result[] = easymeet_create_meeting(1234, new BigBlueButton());
$result[] = easymeet_create_meeting(5678, new BigRedButton());
```

And now we're looking at the rudiments of [Dependency Injection](http://www.phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection), which is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right the problem is not with namespace.

As you said you could try using a global variable for example:

```
use \BigBlueButton;
global $bbb;
$bbb = new BigBlueButton\BigBlueButton();

function easymeet_create_meeting($id) {
    global $bbb;
    // you can use it
}
```

or you can send the variable to the function

```
function easymeet_create_meeting($id, $bbb) {

}
```

I do not know the entire problem, but you could also use a singleton design pattern in the class so you always get the same instance every time you use it.